# finding out the best way to bookmark links and websites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks

good day fellows,

finding out the best way to bookmark links and websites - which tool do you use!?

Consider the following case-scenario: you sit in front of your notebook and you just stumbled across an exciting article you really want to read, unfortunatly you have no time at all at the moment; you have a bunch of work that need to be done before you can sit down and read it.

What can you do?
- leave the text open in your browser. 
- email the the URL-link to yourself, but 
- use the toolset of your browser to bookmark the site...

**question**: is there a more convenient and easy-to-read way.

i have seen some of the following:

- Evernote Web Clipper
- Trello
- Bitly
- Pocket
- Pinterest

and besides the above mentioned i have had a quick view on Digg and Mix and even to Reddit and others more. I would choose a easy to use one.

**Question:** is there a google-tool also available.

which tool do you use!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way is to use the Bookmark function of your browser.
Since you tagged it with chrome and firefox - both are capable of synchronizing
bookmarks since many years now.

1. Log into chrome or create a firefox sync account
2. store bookmark of the site you want to read later. (In chrome you can check your bookmark with chrome://bookmarks/ and see the mobile bookmarks and every device you are on)

If you are searching for an external tool I used "wunderlist.com" for years, no matter if used as a shopping list, to do list or a bookmark list of "sites to read", present ideas for friends, movies to watch and what ever you are up to.
It has a few advantages over trello and co and it was recently bought by microsoft.

Hope that helps you.